# Local storage on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, local-storage

I've built a Rails app, basically a CRUD app for memos/notes.

A notes title must be unique. If a user enters a name already taken a warning message is shown prompting them to chose another.

My question is how to make this latency for this feedback as close to zero as possible. When creating a note little UX speed bumps like this will get annoying for user quickly.

Of course the main bottleneck is the network. Inspired by Meteor (and mini-mongo) I was thinking some kind of local storage could be a solution? 
I.E. When app first loads, send ALL JSON to the client with ALL note titles. The app (front end is Angular JS) could check LocalStorage (or App Cache, Web SQL?) instead of incurring a network round trip. The feedback would be instant.

I've used LocalStorage in the past to augment an app, but in the scenario it'd really seriously depend on it. I'm not sure how confident I'd be building on something that user might not have. Also as the number of user Notes/Memos I have doubts how feasible it is to send a JSON object down the wire with ALL the note titles. That might get pretty big. On the other hand MeteorJS seems to do this with no probs.

Has anyone done something similar or have any pointers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Meteor works here, but you're right that storing all note titles in localStorage is not a good idea. Actually, you don't need localStorage here, you can just put it in a JS array, because you need this data only once (when checking new note title).

I think, there could be 2 possible solutions:

1. You can change your business requirements and allow non-unique title. Is there really a necessity for titles to be unique?
2. You can verify note title when user submits form. In this case you can provide suggestions for users, so they not spend time guessing vacant title.

Or, if titles must be unique only within a user (two users can have same title for their notes), you can really load all note titles in JS array and check uniqueness while users types in a title.

Or you can send an AJAX request checking title uniqueness as soon as user finished typing the title. In this case you can win some seconds.

Or you can send an AJAX request as soon as user typed in 3 symbols. The request will return all titles that begin with these 3 symbols, so you don't need to load all the titles.